# Show the following PDE from the known nonlinear ODE and its solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

> Suppose I have the following nonlinear ODE:
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dt}=F(y)$$ with $y(0) = z$. Suppose the solution of this nonlinear ODE is $y(t,z)$. Show the following:
>
> $$\frac{\partial y(t,z)}{\partial t}\Bigr\rvert_{z \text{ fixed }} -F(z)\frac{\partial y(t,z)}{\partial z} \Bigr\rvert_{t \text{ fixed }} =0$$

---

We can consider the simplest case such as $F(y) = y$. And can solve $y(t) = ze^t$ and then plug into the partial differential equation. We have $F(z) = z$.

---

To formally prove this, I am not sure where to start with. I am also confused about the following,

$$\frac{\partial y(t,z)}{\partial t}\Bigr\rvert_{z \text{ fixed }} = F(z)??$$

If this is true, then $\frac{\partial y(t,z)}{\partial z} \Bigr\rvert_{t \text{ fixed }} = 1$, which does not make any sense obviously.

---

The following is my new work on this:

$$\int_z^y \frac{dy}{F(y)} = \int_{0}^t dt \Rightarrow G(y) - G(z) = t$$
where $$G(y) = \int \frac{dy}{F(y)}, \text{ which is a indefinite integral}$$

Now we have $$G(y) = t + G(z) \Rightarrow y(t,z) = G^{-1}(t + G(z))$$ where
$$G^{-1}(y) = ?$$

I am a bit confused the following:

1. Does the above derivation make sense?
2. What is $G^{-1}$ here?
3. I am also not quite sure the following? $$\frac{\partial G^{-1}(t+G(z))}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial G^{-1}(t+G(z))}{\partial (t+G(z))}\frac{\partial (t+G(z)))}{\partial t} = ? $$

Comment: @daulomb No. We can see the initial value $z$ as a variable here. i.e., we can give arbitrary $z$ to be $y(0)$. That simplest example shows how it works.

Comment: This is a separable ODE, so you can solve it by using an antiderivative of $1/F(y)$. Say, $G(y)$ is a function such that $G'(y) = 1/F(y)$.

Comment: @Michael You mean solve for $y$ by antiderivative of $F(y)$, and then plug into the partial differential equation to show it, correct?  Thanks!